# Questions no longer sorted by upvotes?

Tags: support, up-votes, sorting

Are questions no longer sorted by upvotes? Or it just me?

Comment: Check what tab you're on.

Comment: @random I've started noticing this problem in the las couple of weeks - has something changed recently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For The Questions Page:**

You can sort by newest, active, featured, 'hot', and number of votes.

**For The Home Page:**

You can sort by active, featured, 'hot', and best of week or month.

**For The Unanswered Page:**

You can sort by the newest questions with your tag, the newest, or votes.

**For Answers:**

You can sort by Votes, Time (ASC), or Time (DESC).

Just click one of the tabs right above the first answer.

Comment: ok but does it remember what you've previously selected and apply that to all future pageviews?

Comment: Yes, the tab you've selected is remembered.

Comment: Only on that section. If you filter by 'Votes' on the unanswered page, it only does that for the unanswered section.

Comment: I <3 My Tags in Unanswered.

Comment: I'm starting to notice this problem just now. It looks like questions stopped being sorted by upvotes in the last few days.